# How to print only integers that are true in a column in jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

Uploading a CSV , and importing pandas, and matplotlib, I produce 10k rows, and some of the rows in "attachments" have attachments and some do not. I would like to know how to make print only the rows with 1 or more attachments associated with them and disregard the ones that have zero.

```
df[["to","from","attachments"]] # created a list of names to filter through
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this one :

```py
df[df["attachments"] >= 1]
```

To answer your commentary :

> Is there a way to have this result, in conjunction with the attachments that have only 1 or more with "to", "from"

```py
df[(df["attachments"] >= 1) & (df["to"] >= 1) & (df["from"] >= 1)]
```

Comment: This definitely helped. Is there a way to have this result, in conjunction with the attachments that have only 1 or more with "to", "from", only?  I get the following as of right now: date user pc to cc bcc from size attachments content, but I would like to only have attachments with 1 or more, to, and from filtered down. Thank you